# How to Upload Images using React, fetch, and Django REST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, fetch

I'm encountering a bit of a roadblock in my dev work. I'm trying to upload a photo that I'm sending using FormData in fetch. I'm guessing my problem is in my content header or my back-end handling. Eitherway, I can't seem to find a way around it. I hope you guys can help me

**general.js** - this is my handler for a request

```
 export const postDataWithImage = (url, data) => {
        return fetch(url, {
            body: data, // must match 'Content-Type' header
            credentials: 'same-origin', //pass cookies, for authentication
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON
    };
```

**user-creation.js** - my actual usage of the function above (sending multiple data)

heres an image of the data I'm sending 
![1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/u00Xj.jpg

```
const data = {...this.state, ...form};
        const formData = new FormData();
        Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value));

postDataWithImage('/users', data)
            .then(data => {
                if (data.error) {
                    console.log("theres an error");
                    this.setState({
                        error: data["error"]
                    });
                    console.log(this.state.error);
                } else {
                    console.log(data["data"]);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => message.warning(error.message));
```

**views.py** - my backend handler using Django REST not: this returns me an error either byte has no attribute 'get'... or an empty ModelDict for request.FILES

```
  @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        print(request.body.get('image'))
        print(request.FILES)
        if "username" not in request.data or "password" not in request.data:
            return Response(data={
                "error": "Missing username or password"
            }, status=400, content_type="application/json")
        return Response(data=data, status=200, content_type="application/json")
```

Please help me I'm really stuck. Thank you!

Comment: Have you succeeded in sending a request to your backend with e.g. Postman?

Comment: Yes I sent the request to the backend. The main problem is the backend  can't read the files/data properly.

Comment: Alright. Could you include what your `this.state` and `form` look like before you put it in `data`?

Comment: well the form, when console.logged is this https://imgur.com/leBlC7L

Comment: Also, if I stringify the FormData (which I think will break the image format), all the information I need can be retrieved by calling request.data

Comment: Alright. That's frustrating. I'm not sure what's wrong, but it looks like your `image` file has been converted to a regular object. It might be that some information is lost if you don't append the `File` to the `FormData`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem using Vue.js and Django.
Finally I noticed that the problem was that: **`boundary` was not set to the header.**

The solution is to remove `headers` from your request like this:

```js
fetch(url, {
            body: data,  // assume this is some binary data
            method: 'POST',
})
```

Then, your browser will automatically add proper headers for your request. And you will see `boundary` field which is added by your browser in your request headers.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the "Content-Type" from the headers of fetch